# Calculate percentage given condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, percentage, dplyr

I am new to this website and to coding as well. I was wondering if any of you could help me out

I need to calculate the Top 5 Movies, by rating distribution, calculating the percentage of ratings for each movie that are 4 stars or higher.

So far I was only able to calculate the number of occurrences using dplyr.

Is it possible to calculate it using dplyr (something similar to my coding)?

I'm not sure whether I need to mutate to come up with the solution or if there's another way to do so.

My code so far:

```
dfAux1 <- na.omit(dfAux)
dfAux1 %>%
  group_by(movie) %>%
  summarise(tot = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(tot))%>%
  head(5)
```

the result should be something like this:

```
**Expected result**:
0.7000000, 'The Shawshank Redemption'
0.5333333, 'Star Wars IV - A New Hope'
0.5000000, 'Gladiator'
0.4444444, 'Blade Runner'
0.4375000, 'The Silence of the Lambs'
```

and so far this is my result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
                              movie   tot
                             <fctr> <int>
1                         Toy Story    17
2          The Silence of the Lambs    16
3         Star Wars IV - A New Hope    15
4 Star Wars VI - Return of the Jedi    14
5                  Independence Day    13
```

edit:

```
str(dfAux1)
'data.frame':   241 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Rating: int  1 5 4 2 4 5 4 2 3 2 ...
 $ movie : Factor w/ 20 levels "Star Wars IV - A New Hope",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:159] 3 4 7 16 17 23 27 28 34 36 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:159] "3" "4" "7" "16" ...

dput(dfAux1)
structure(list(Rating = c(1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L), movie = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("Star Wars IV - A New Hope", 
"Star Wars VI - Return of the Jedi", "Forrest Gump", "The Shawshank Redemption", 
"The Silence of the Lambs", "Gladiator", "Toy Story", "Saving Private Ryan", 
"Pulp Fiction", "Stand by Me", "Shakespeare in Love", "Total Recall", 
"Independence Day", "Blade Runner", "Groundhog Day", "The Matrix", 
"Schindler's List", "The Sixth Sense", "Raiders of the Lost Ark", 
"Babe"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Rating", "movie"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 70L, 73L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 104L, 105L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 111L, 115L, 116L, 118L, 119L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 
134L, 135L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 
149L, 150L, 153L, 156L, 159L, 160L, 164L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 
172L, 175L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 185L, 186L, 
189L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
209L, 212L, 216L, 217L, 219L, 220L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 
228L, 229L, 231L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 239L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 
246L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 261L, 263L, 
264L, 265L, 267L, 268L, 274L, 278L, 280L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 286L, 
288L, 289L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 300L, 301L, 303L, 305L, 
307L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 314L, 316L, 317L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 
323L, 324L, 325L, 328L, 330L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 338L, 340L, 341L, 
342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 348L, 350L, 351L, 356L, 358L, 360L, 
362L, 363L, 364L, 367L, 368L, 371L, 373L, 375L, 376L, 378L, 380L, 
383L, 384L, 386L, 387L, 389L, 391L, 392L, 395L, 396L, 398L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 7L, 16L, 17L, 23L, 27L, 28L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 61L, 64L, 68L, 71L, 72L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 84L, 86L, 91L, 99L, 103L, 106L, 110L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 117L, 120L, 125L, 127L, 136L, 142L, 143L, 148L, 151L, 
152L, 154L, 155L, 157L, 158L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 165L, 169L, 171L, 
173L, 174L, 176L, 184L, 187L, 188L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 197L, 
198L, 203L, 204L, 208L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 218L, 221L, 
227L, 230L, 232L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 240L, 245L, 247L, 256L, 257L, 
258L, 259L, 260L, 262L, 266L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 279L, 281L, 285L, 287L, 290L, 291L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 
302L, 304L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 313L, 315L, 318L, 326L, 327L, 329L, 
331L, 332L, 333L, 337L, 339L, 347L, 349L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 
357L, 359L, 361L, 365L, 366L, 369L, 370L, 372L, 374L, 377L, 379L, 
381L, 382L, 385L, 388L, 390L, 393L, 394L, 397L, 399L, 400L), .Names = c("3", 
"4", "7", "16", "17", "23", "27", "28", "34", "36", "37", "42", 
"43", "44", "48", "49", "50", "53", "55", "57", "59", "61", "64", 
"68", "71", "72", "74", "75", "76", "77", "79", "84", "86", "91", 
"99", "103", "106", "110", "112", "113", "114", "117", "120", 
"125", "127", "136", "142", "143", "148", "151", "152", "154", 
"155", "157", "158", "161", "162", "163", "165", "169", "171", 
"173", "174", "176", "184", "187", "188", "190", "191", "192", 
"193", "197", "198", "203", "204", "208", "210", "211", "213", 
"214", "215", "218", "221", "227", "230", "232", "236", "237", 
"238", "240", "245", "247", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", 
"262", "266", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", "275", "276", 
"277", "279", "281", "285", "287", "290", "291", "297", "298", 
"299", "302", "304", "306", "308", "309", "313", "315", "318", 
"326", "327", "329", "331", "332", "333", "337", "339", "347", 
"349", "352", "353", "354", "355", "357", "359", "361", "365", 
"366", "369", "370", "372", "374", "377", "379", "381", "382", 
"385", "388", "390", "393", "394", "397", "399", "400"), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: Please `dput` and share dataframe containing details of movies.

Comment: You should use `dput(dfAux1)` and share output please. `str` wont help much.

Comment: I did, it looks awful hehehe

Comment: Thanks. Have a look at my single line solution using `data.table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single line solution using `data.table` and data from OP could be as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfAux1)[, .(pct = sum(Rating>=4)/.N), by=movie][order(-pct)][1:5]
                  movie        pct
1:  The Shawshank Redemption 0.7000000
2: Star Wars IV - A New Hope 0.5333333
3:                 Gladiator 0.5000000
4:              Blade Runner 0.4444444
5:  The Silence of the Lambs 0.4375000
```

Comment: Thank you! not sure whether I am happy or mad that you were able to do it with just one line of code hehehe

Answer (score 3):

I am using `data.table` instead of `dplyr`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfAux1)  # make dfAux1 as data table by reference

# calculate total number by movies, then compute percent for `Rating >= 4` by movies and then sort `tot` by descending order and also eliminating duplicates in movies using `.SD[1]` which gives the first row in each movie. 
dfAux1[, .(Rating, tot = .N), by = movie ][Rating >= 4, .(percent = .N/tot, tot), by = movie ][order(-tot), .SD[1], by = movie]

#                                movie    percent tot
# 1:                         Toy Story 0.35294118  17
# 2:          The Silence of the Lambs 0.43750000  16
# 3:         Star Wars IV - A New Hope 0.53333333  15
# 4: Star Wars VI - Return of the Jedi 0.35714286  14
# 5:                  Independence Day 0.30769231  13
# 6:                         Gladiator 0.50000000  12
# 7:                      Total Recall 0.08333333  12
# 8:                     Groundhog Day 0.41666667  12
# 9:                        The Matrix 0.41666667  12
# 10:                  Schindler's List 0.33333333  12
# 11:                   The Sixth Sense 0.33333333  12
# 12:               Saving Private Ryan 0.36363636  11
# 13:                      Pulp Fiction 0.36363636  11
# 14:                       Stand by Me 0.36363636  11
# 15:               Shakespeare in Love 0.27272727  11
# 16:           Raiders of the Lost Ark 0.27272727  11
# 17:                      Forrest Gump 0.30000000  10
# 18:          The Shawshank Redemption 0.70000000  10
# 19:                              Babe 0.40000000  10
# 20:                      Blade Runner 0.44444444   9
```

Comment: that's not exactly what I am trying to do, for instance, Gladiator has 12 reviews and out of these 12 reviews 6 were rated 4 or 5, therefore the number I was looking for is 50%.

Comment: it works! thanks, I'd just need to order by the top 5

Answer (score 2):

## Overview

I used the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package to group your data by the `movie` column and perform calculations based on the `rating` column.

In [`summarise()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/summarise), I created three new columns:

1. `Total_Review`: counts the total number of reviews per `movie`.
2. `FourPlus_Rating`: counts the subset of reviews with a `Rating` value of 4 or higher.
3. `Per_FourPlus_Rating`: divides `FourPlus_Rating` by `Total_Review`.

I then arranged the date in descending order based on `Per_FourPlus_Rating`. Finally, I called [`head()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/head.html) to specify that I only want the [`tibble`](http://tibble.tidyverse.org/) to return the first 5 rows.

## Reproducible Example

```
# install necessary package
install.packages( pkgs = "dplyr" )

# load necessary package
library( dplyr )


# view first six rows
head( x = df )
#   Rating                     movie
# 1      1 Star Wars IV - A New Hope
# 2      5 Star Wars IV - A New Hope
# 5      4 Star Wars IV - A New Hope
# 6      2 Star Wars IV - A New Hope
# 8      4 Star Wars IV - A New Hope
# 9      5 Star Wars IV - A New Hope

# perform calculations using 
# dplyr functions
df %>%
  group_by( movie ) %>%
  summarise( Total_Review              = n()
             , FourPlus_Rating         = length( Rating[ which( Rating >= 4 ) ] )
             , Per_FourPlus_Rating     = length( Rating[ which( Rating >= 4 ) ] ) / n() ) %>%
  arrange( desc( Per_FourPlus_Rating ) ) %>%
  head( n = 5 )
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# movie               Total_Review FourPlus_Rating Per_FourPlus_Rati…
# <fct>                      <int>           <int>              <dbl>
# 1 The Shawshank Rede…           10               7              0.700
# 2 Star Wars IV - A N…           15               8              0.533
# 3 Gladiator                     12               6              0.500
# 4 Blade Runner                   9               4              0.444
# 5 The Silence of the…           16               7              0.438

# end of script #
```

Comment: I think it should be something (at least what I am looking for) to what you did, the only problem is that I need to count the number of occurrences instead of summing.
For example, gladiator has 12 reviews and 6 of those are rated >=4 which should yield 0.5

Comment: Oh, you fixed, thank you!
It worked, could not figure it out that it was length...I really appreciate you helping me out

Comment: Thank you for sharing the desired output! I added some explanation up top. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. May be you can remove the definition of `df` and that has been included in OP itself. It will make your post very clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks @MKR! I didn't realize how ugly it looked haha much cleaner now!

Answer (score 0):

this is a dplyr solution:

```
    dfAuxhigh=filter(dfAux1,Rating>=4)%>%group_by(movie)%>%summarize(percentHigh=n())
dfAux=dfAux1%>%group_by(movie)%>%summarize(percentAll=n())
result<-merge(dfAuxhigh,dfAux,by="movie")%>%mutate(percentage=percentHigh/percentAll)
result<-result[order(result$percentage,decreasing = T)[1:5],c(1,4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(movie, Rating) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%           #< get freq of movies
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%      #< find perc for each rating, by movie
  filter(Rating >=4) %>%           #< filter for desired rating (4 or above) 
  summarise(freq = sum(freq)) %>%  #< summarize again
  top_n(5) %>%                     
  arrange(desc(freq)) %>% 
  mutate(freq = paste0(round(freq*100, 2), "%"))

#>   movie                     freq  
#> 1 The Shawshank Redemption  70%  
#> 2 Star Wars IV - A New Hope 53.33%
#> 3 Gladiator                 50%   
#> 4 Blade Runner              44.44%
#> 5 The Silence of the Lambs  43.75%
```